# How to define two variable x=20, y=5 and then to print division of x and y (i.e. x/y) - bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and i tried this :

```
$ x=20  
$ y=5  
$ expr x / y
```

But i got this error:

```
expr: non-integer argument
```

Answer (score 0):

You must expand the variables to get their values: `$x` and `$y`:

```
expr $x / $y
```

Comment: `expr` is obsolute, avoid it when possible (see my answer)

Comment: It isn't obsolete, it is the only thing available in POSIX shell programming. It has just been replaced in advanced shells by arithmetic operators such as `((..))`. But as a general statement, I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using modern Bash arithmetics:

```
echo $((x / y))
```

To assign the result to a variable `z`:

```
((z = x / y))
```

To verify the value of `z`:

```
echo $z
```